# Validate Azure token in a Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have an application with a React FrontEnd and a spring boot backend. Here is my problem: I have to autorize my frontend in my back with my microsoft token. From here I manage to :

1. From my front page when I click on my login button it redirect me to
   azure connection portal (I used msal.js library)
2. After the redirection, I have an access token.

Now, I want to send this access token to my back (something like /api/auth), call the microsoft graph api to retrieve users informations, create the user in my DataBase if he doesn't exists and then return information with a token that will allow my front to be authorized when it requests protected endpoints

Answer (score 1):

Please use [these](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-spring-boot-samples/tree/main/aad/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory) samples for your reference. Mostly we will use either of the ADD resource server approach.

Hope you have the necessary dependencies in your application(azure-core, azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client, spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server and the normal spring web dependency).

The JWT token which you recived through frontend can be attached as a barer token with each request you are making to the spring boot app.

Include the below class for validating the azure JWT token.

```
import com.azure.spring.aad.webapi.AADJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(new AADJwtBearerTokenAuthenticationConverter());
    }
}
```

In case you come acorss with corss issue please add a filter to attach corss orgin in header.
Hope it will help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29841976)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security can be used to validate the token, you can take a look at [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapi/tree/edbd399155341556e3871065d1b8b4be2e9cbce0).